# Swift Combine: sink() called after core data entity deletion

Tags: swift, combine

I am using this code in a SwiftUI view model:

```
    car.publisher(for: \.sold, options: [.new])
        .removeDuplicates()
        .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
        .sink { [weak self] sold in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            .... here is reference the car entity for some logic ....
        }
        .store(in: &subscribers)
```

All works fine, until I actually delete that Car entity and the sink kicks in and then `.... here is reference the car entity for some logic ....` runs and it crashes trying to use a DELETED Core Data entity.

My pattern seems to be wrong here. Is there a way for that sink to cancel automatically when that car entity is deleted from context?

Comment: Have you tried making the `car` property a weak property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `faultingState` to track this scenario. From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506720-faultingstate):

> `0` if the object is fully initialized as a managed object and not transitioning to or from another state, otherwise some other value. This property allows you to determine if an object is in a transitional phase when receiving a key-value observing change notification.

So you can ignore this event like this:

```
.sink { [weak self] sold in
    guard let self = self, car.faultingState == 0 else { return }
    //
}
```

---

If you wanna actually cancel this sink, you can store cancellables inside the object so you can cancel them during [`prepareForDeletion`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobject/1506674-preparefordeletion).

To do this you need to change object code generation, more info can be found [here](https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/core-data-code-generation/). Change to **Category/Extension** - in this case you can create a class and override `prepareForDeletion`, and Xcode will still generate all the properties for you.

Now you can move all publisher logic into your class:

```
@objc(Car)
public class Car: NSManagedObject {
    private var subscribers = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    func observe<Value: Equatable>(keyPath: KeyPath<Item, Value>, receiveValue: @escaping ((Value) -> Void)) {
        publisher(for: keyPath, options: [.new])
            .removeDuplicates()
            .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
            .sink(receiveValue: receiveValue)
            .store(in: &subscribers)
    }

    public override func prepareForDeletion() {
        super.prepareForDeletion()
        subscribers.removeAll()
    }
}
```

Or just use it to store cancellables.